# Rails3: How to set bash environment variables that are project-specific?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

My apps use several environment variables (in ~/.bashrc on my local dev machine, and as heroku config vars on the remote heroku app).

Since all ENV vars on my local machine are in the same file, I have to be careful naming them to avoid collisions between different apps.

How do I set environment variables on my local machine that are specific to the particular app I'm running locally?

For example, to run app_one locally:

```
cd app_one  
run_something (that loads the env vars then runs rails server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using [RVM](https://rvm.io) then you can put your app-specific environment variables in your application's `.rvmrc` files.

For example, suppose you have two applications, `pancakes` and `eggs`, set up like this:

```
~/src/pancakes/
~/src/eggs/
```

and two `.rvmrc` files like this:

```
# ~/src/pancakes/.rvmrc
export APP_NAME=pancakes

# ~/src/eggs/.rvmrc
export APP_NAME=eggs
```

Then:

```
$ cd ~/src/pancakes
$ echo $APP_NAME
pancakes
$ cd ~/src/eggs
$ echo $APP_NAME
eggs
```

This approach has the added advantage of keeping all of your application-specific settings with your application and it makes it easy to keep your application-specific environment variables under revision control. You could also hook up a little parser to your publishing process to extract the necessary settings from your `.rvmrc` file and set them on Heroku.

Comment: @RedX: Thanks, I fixed the link.

Answer (score 2):

1) You could create a wrapper shell script that sets the env vars and then invokes the server (eg, `script/rails s` )

2) You can define them on the command line:
`RAILS_ENV=production MYTHICAL_VAR=someserver:8080 script/rails s`

3) You could set these variables in your app's initializer script

Answer (score 2):

Save this script, then execute as ./somescript.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash
export FOO=bar
exec some_other_command
```